# Forge InstanceTree getNodeType() returning 0

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I would like to filter the elements according to their native category (not using ACC) so I'm looking at the InstanceTree of the Viewer. According to the documentation the InstanceTree's **getNodeType()** method should return an integer (from `viewer.js` file NODE_TYPE should be: 0x0, 0x1, 0x2 ... 0x7), but what I get from my Revit model is always a value of 0. What does it stay for?
I'm interested to the abstract collection of objects (e.g. Doors)...is there a better approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Even though the node types are exposed by the instance tree, they are more of an internal implementation detail that probably won't be helpful for what you're trying to do. FYI these are the meanings of the different values:

- `0x0` - `NODE_TYPE_ASSEMBLY`
- `0x1` - `NODE_TYPE_INSERT`
- `0x2` - `NODE_TYPE_LAYER`
- `0x3` - `NODE_TYPE_COLLECTION`
- `0x4` - `NODE_TYPE_COMPOSITE`
- `0x5` - `NODE_TYPE_MODEL`
- `0x6` - `NODE_TYPE_GEOMETRY`
- `0x7` - `NODE_TYPE_BITS`

If you're interested in classifying objects in models coming from Revit designs, you could use the standard Viewer API such as [search](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#search-text-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback-attributenames-options), [getProperties](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#getproperties-dbid-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback), or [getBulkProperties](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Model/#getbulkproperties-dbids-options-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback), and use some of the object properties. For Revit designs specifically, each object will include a property called `Category` that can be something like `Revit Doors`, `Revit Curtain Panels`, etc.

Comment: ok, I changed the approach and now get the classification of the elements from the InstanceTree, using some basic understanding of the Revit structure. Unfortunately the Category property is not referred to the native one, but to the "groups" in the properties panel, and I couldn't find the native category in the manifest (that's why I suggest to have a look at the tree).